# Для генератора безопасных паролей нужно сделать функцию pas

Tags: python, tkinter

Уже прикрепил функцию к кнопке(он на ткинтере). Осталось сделать завершительную функцию к генератору.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Генератор Безопасных Паролей')
digits = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
uppercase_letters = [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)]
lowercase_letters = [chr(x) for x in range(97, 123)]
punctuation = list('!#$%&*+-=?@^_?')
nonechars = ['i', 'l', '1', 'L', 'o', '0', 'O']

q = [
    ['Включать ли цифры 0123456789?(Да-1, Нет-0):', digits],
    ['Включать ли прописные буквы ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?', uppercase_letters],
    ['Включать ли строчные буквы abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz?', lowercase_letters],
    ['Включать ли символы !#$%&*+-=?@^_?', punctuation],
    ['Включать ли неоднозначные символы il1Lo0O?', nonechars]]

jk = tk.Label(text='Включать ли?(Да-1, Нет-0)', bg='Black', fg='White', width=22, font=20)
jk.pack()

global answers
for i in range(len(q)):
    que = tk.Label(text=q[i][1], width=60, font='Rubik', fg='dim grey')
    que.pack()
    an = tk.Entry(bg='SlateGray1', width=10)
    an.pack()

def pas():


but = tk.Button(text='Показать пароль', bg='indian red', command=pas)
but.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: забирайте код и я грохну ответ

Comment: Спасибо бро!!!!